# Platform for mobile game feedback

Tags: mobile, steam

I am designing a small mobile game. Eventually i am going to release it on Play store and App store. But is there any platform such as Steam Greenlight where I can put my concept or demo and get some good helpful feedbacks before I put it in market.

I found that GOG accepts mobile games but don't know about their process. So can GOG be helpful for me?

(I am sorry if the question is duplicate. Couldn't find any proper answer on google.)

Comment: Do you intend to launch it on both pc and mobile?

Comment: @ZEKE no only mobile